# Covariance contravariance error in Scala

Tags: scala, covariance

I tried to compile the following piece of code:

```
class A[-T]
class B[-T] extends A[A[T]]
```

I obtain the following error:

```
error: contravariant type T occurs in covariant position in type [-T]A[A[T]]{def <init>(): B[T]} of class B
```

Why is this an error?

Comment: `<init>` is the constructor, and it is defined implicitly.

Comment: Then why can I define `class B[-T]`? The method `init` would exist as well and return me a `B[T]` and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is an error because `A[A[T]]` is *covariant* in type T.

Definition of covariant type from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)):

> Within the type system of a programming language, a typing rule or a
>   type constructor is:
>
> - covariant if it preserves the ordering of types (≤), which orders types from more specific to more generic;
> - contravariant if it reverses this ordering;

Consider the following:

```
class Fruit
class Banana extends Fruit
```

and

```
Banana <: Fruit
A[Banana] :> A[Fruit] // Because A is contravariant in type T
A[A[Banana]] <: A[A[Fruit]] // Again because A is contravariant in type T
```

The last statement means that `A[A[T]]` is *covariant* since it preserves the ordering of types from more specific to more generic.

So it possible to do:

```
scala> type AA[+T] = A[A[T]]
defined type alias AA

scala> type AAA[-T] = A[A[A[T]]]
defined type alias AAA
```

But the following will lead to error:

```
scala> type AA[-T] = A[A[T]]
<console>:15: error: contravariant type T occurs in covariant position in type [-T]A[A[T]] of type AA
       type AA[-T] = A[A[T]]
            ^

scala> type AAA[+T] = A[A[A[T]]]
<console>:15: error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type [+T]A[A[A[T]]] of type AAA
       type AAA[+T] = A[A[A[T]]]
            ^
```

And finally returning to the original question there is the same violation of the variance rule in `class B` definition since the base class `A[A[T]]` is covariant in type `T` by construction.

To understand why it is prohibited let's assume it is possible:

```
class B[-T] extends A[A[T]]
```

In this case we get:

```
B[Fruit] <: B[Banana] <: A[A[Banana]]
```

so

```
val fruits: B[Fruit] = new B[Fruit]
val bananas1: B[Banana] = fruits
val bananas2: A[A[Banana]] = bananas1
```

Now we have a value `bananas2` of type `A[A[Banana]]` which points to an instance of `A[A[Fruit]]` which violates type-safety since `A[A[Banana]] <: A[A[Fruit]]`.

Comment: So you're right, I cannot define `type AA[-T] = A[A[T]]`. But for my original question, what about defining a class which *extends* `A[A[T]]` but defines `T` as contravariant parameter?

Comment: @MikaëlMayer I updated the answer to cover the original question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

`<init>` is the constructor of `A` (or `B`), defined by the compiler.

The problem with the code is that `B[-T] extends A[A[T]]` leads to a contradiction.

Take this example:

```
class A[-T]
class B[-T] extends A[A[T]]

class Animal
class Cat extends Animal
```

For short-hand, let's use `A <: B` to signify that *`A` is a sub-type of `B`*.

Since both `A` and `B` are contravariant over their type parameters `T`, and `Cat <: Animal`, then

```
A[Animal] <: A[Cat]
B[Animal] <: B[Cat]
```

Since `A[Animal] <: A[Cat]`, then (again because of the contravariance of `A`):

```
A[A[Cat]] <: A[A[Animal]]
```

Also, by the definition of `B`:

```
B[Cat] = A[A[Cat]]
B[Animal] = A[A[Animal]]
```

We already know that `B[Animal] <: B[Cat]`, but if we translate these types to their above equivalances, we get:

```
B[Animal] <: B[Cat] => A[A[Animal]] <: A[A[Cat]]
```

But we already showed that `A[A[Cat]] <: A[A[Animal]]`. We end up with an impossible situation.

Comment: It is not true that B[Cat] = A[A[Cat]]. At most you have that B[Cat] <: A[A[Cat]]

Comment: It is, though. A `B[Cat]` is a `A[A[Cat]]` just as a `List[A]` is also a `Seq[A]` or an `Int` is an `AnyVal`. If a class extends something, then it _is_ that thing. An upper-bound is not strict.

Comment: The fact that a `B[Cat]` is a `A[A[Cat]]` is not equality because we are talking about types. Your final implication relies on the wrong assumption that if `A <: B`, `C <: D` and `A <: C` then we would have `B <: D`, which is obviously wrong. No I'm really sorry but your answer is not correct. At most you get the following:
`B[Animal] <: B[Cat] <: A[A[Cat]] <: A[A[Animal]`